# Вылетает Genymotion (app crashed) на некоторых layout с background

Tags: java, android

На эмуляторе Genymotion слабые версии Андроид (например, Lg Optimus l3 II 240x320) спокойно выдерживает layout (Linear) с background (фото размером 750 X 1216) весом 670 кб.

А новые версии андроид с большим разрешением экрана (например, google nexus 6  1440X2560) крашатся на главном  layout (где этот самый Linear с background), как только убираю параметр background, все сразу работает.
В связи с чем несколько вопросов:

1. Может ли эмулятор "лагать"? То есть на самом деле, на устройствах всё будет хорошо, глючит только эмулятор. Насколько это реально? Или полная ерунда и эмулятор показывает реальную картину?
2. Может ли быть вызвано "падение" приложения тем, что экран эмулируемого смартфона больше, чем физический размер картинки (у LinearLayout с background стоит fill_parent на ширину и Fill_parent на высоту)? Просто предположение.
3. Если все вышеизложенное неверно, прошу посоветовать мне хоть какое-то решение, а то запарился уже!

Comment: Стактрейс эксцепшена в студию!

Comment: Да, трейс нужен, не в ту сторону копаете. Там либо OOM, либо что-то такое. Большие картинки вручную уменьшать нужно под экран.

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.